# Smallest "n" sums from n arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum

I was trying to do my friends problem set from a few years ago to sharpen up my knowledge about data structures etc. I came across this problem, and I'm not really sure where to start. Hopefully someone could help me out!

We are given n unsorted arrays, each array has n elements. Ex.

```
3 1 2
7 6 9
4 9 12
```

Now, say we take one element from each array, and add them up. Lets just call the sum of these elements an "n-sum".

I need to devise an algorithm that gives us the n smallest "n-sums" (duplicates are allowed).

In our above ex, the answer would be:

```
11, 12, 12

# 11 comes from: 1 (first array) + 6 (second array) + 4 (third array)
# 12 comes from: 2 (first array) + 6 (second array) + 4 (third array)
# 12 comes from: 1 (first array) + 7 (second array) + 4 (third array)
```

One of the suggestions given were to use a priority queue.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems to me that for this example the answer should be `11, 12, 12`, where the last sum is `1 + 7 + 4`. Furthermore, English being only my third language, I don't understand the phrase “duplicates aloud”.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. My mistake.

Comment: What complexity do you expect? It's easy to think of a brute force solution. But I think you want something better than that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I remember my friend had to actually code it, and there was time limits on each test case. I doubt brute forcing is the way to go. If I recall correctly, it was an algorithm / data structures course.

Comment: Can you tell the constrains on n? Is this problem up on some online judge?

Comment: I believe 2 <= n <= 800. I just have a handout in my hand. Sorry about that. Let me know if you need any more information and Ill let you know. I guess I should've included this in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The time is at least O (n^2): You must visit all array elements, because if all elements were equal to 1000 except on in each row being 0, you would have to look at the n elements equal to 0, or you couldn't find the smallest sum.

Sort each row, taking O (n^2 log n) steps. In each row, subtract the first element from all elements in the row, so the first element in each row is 0; after you found the smallest sums you can compensate for that. Your example turns into

```
3 1 2  -> 1 2 3 -> 0 1 2
7 6 9  -> 6 7 9 -> 0 1 3
4 9 12 -> 4 9 12-> 0 5 7
```

Now finding all sums ≤ K can be done in m steps if there are m sums: In the first row, pick all values in turn as long as they are ≤ K. In the second row, pick all values in turn as long as the sum from two rows is ≤ K and so on. Since each row starts with 0, no time is wasted.

For example, sums ≤ 5 are: 0+0+0, 0+0+5, 0+1+0, 0+3+0, 1+0+0, 1+1+0, 1+3+0, 2+0+0, 2+1+0, 2+3+0. Many more than the three that we needed. If we stop after finding 3 sums ≤ 5, we know very quickly "there are at least 3 sums ≤ 5". We need to have an early stop, because in the general case there could be n^n possible sums.

If you pick K = "largest element in the second column", then you know there are at least n+1 sums with a value ≤ K, because you can pick all 0's, or all 0's except one value from the second column. In your example, K = 5 (we know that worked). Let X be the value where there are n sums ≤ X but fewer than n sums ≤ X - 1. We find X with binary search between 0 and K, and then we find the sums. Example:

K = 5 is known to be big enough. We try K = 2, and find 4 sums (actually we stop at 3 sums). Too many. We try K = 1, and there are three solutions 0+0+0, 0+1+0 and 1+0+0. We try K = 0, but only one solution.

This part goes very quick, so we'd try to reduce the time used for sorting. We notice that in this case looking at the first two columns was enough. We can in each row find the two smallest items, and in this case that would be enough. If the two smallest items are not enough to determine the n smallest sums, find the third smallest item etc. where needed. For example, since the 2nd largest item of the last row is 5, we wouldn't need the third item of the row, because even the 5 is not element of a sum if K ≤ 4.

Comment: Hmm. Would there be any chance we could try using a priority queue? I really want to try using the structures that were learned in the course my friend was taking.

Comment: What values do you want to put into the priority queue? And how many? You mentioned n = 800. If you just pick the smallest or second smallest value from each row, that's 2^800 combinations. Ridiculously larger than you could ever handle.

Comment: If you subtract the values, wont the numbers in the sum change? I dont think I can have the number "5" in the sum, It was never there to begin with.